# log4net does not write log into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, log4net

I'm trying to log using log4net into my database. I've installed log4net using NuGet and set up my `web.config` like this:

```
<configSections>    
    <!-- Log4Net -->
    <section name="log4net" 
             type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <!--AdoNet appender is use for write log file into SQL Server-->
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <bufferSize value="1" />
        <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <connectionString value="data source=localhost/SVILUPPO;Initial Catalog=MIODB;user id=sa;password=myPassword;" />
        <commandText value="INSERT INTO AppLog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@log_date" />
            <dbType value="DateTime" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@thread" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="255" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>

</appender>

<!--Add appender which you want to use, You can add more then one appender . Like if you want save log both plain text or sql server ,Add both appender.-->

    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
        <!--Enable this line if you want write log file into sql server-->
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Then I set in my `global.asax` the call to the configuration:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

And this in the page where I want get and save the log

```
private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Login));

log.Debug("Debug message");
log.Warn("Warn message");
log.Error("Error message");
log.Fatal("Fatal message");
```

but nothing happens :(

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Just going over the basics: that connection works and that `AppLog` table is defined correctly?

Comment: where do you have set the `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` on `global.asax` ?

Comment: The connection working good i tested it with a normal select. The Table is defined correctly.

Comment: - Aristos yes i set Configure() in global.asax on Start_Application and i try into the class too before log.debug("message")

Comment: No one can help me?

Comment: @UgoBasile was this ever resolved? I'm running into a similar issue because I need to save log level as an int.

Comment: Yes i did, i create a separete  log4net config file. And in web config set just the connections tring

Answer (score 2):

To find the error you can best enable internal debugging in log4net. An error in log4net will not go to your application. You can write it to a log and then see why your logging is not working.

In your app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>

...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

[Log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)